# Converting Chi square to F-values

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme, chi-squared-test, linear-model, f-statistic

I am running Type II sum of squares tests on my linear models using the Anova() function. I prefer Type II over Type III due to its hierarchical nature. With this function, however, I am only getting Chi square values. This wouldn't be a problem if I wasn't specifically requested to report F. I am able to get F values from a Type III sum of square test using the anova(type='marginal') function, but the Anova(type="III") function also only returns Chi square. My question is, is there a way to do a Type II sum of squares test from nlme() linear models and return an F-value? If not, is there a function in R or an easy calculation to convert Chi square to F? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Which Anova function are you using?  First, R is case sensitive. You have anova in your title, but Anova in your text.  Second, Anova (cap) exists in at least two packages (car and nlme) and maybe more.

Comment: More details are needed. It's important to understand *why* it's giving Chi-squared values (albeit that we might be able to make some guesses as to likely reasons), so we need context about what, exactly you're doing. It's frequently the case that there isn't a solid argument that a given statistic has an F distribution (so treating it as if it did would be dubious), but very often it's possible to make an asymptotic chi-squared argument for a closely related quantity or an analog of a closely related quantity.

Comment: I apologize, I should clarify. The Anova() function with the car package is giving Chi square values, and I am able to get F values using anova() type III tests, but not with Anova() type II or III tests. I am running linear models using the nlme() function, so it should have an F-statistic, as from my understanding, Chi square and F values are related in linear mixed models. I'm not sure if there is a way to do a type II test with anova(), and I haven't found a solid answer using Google. Thank you in advance!